# Setting Bash history sizes to -1 clears the history

Tags: bash, command-history

I want to save all my bash history so I set my Bash history sizes in `~/.bash_profile` to negative values:

```bsh
export HISTSIZE=-1
export HISTFILESIZE=-1
```

According to the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-HISTFILESIZE), all my commands should be saved:

> `HISTFILESIZE`: ... Non-numeric values and numeric values less than zero inhibit truncation.
>
> `HISTSIZE`: ... Numeric values less than zero result in every command being saved on the history list (there is no limit).

But this deletes all my history, like [the comments from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454837/bash-histsize-vs-histfilesize/39995739#39995739):

> This is dead wrong. Setting it to -1 will clear everything.

Setting the values to a string does not clear my bash history, as in another comment:

> I changed my settings to `HISTSIZE='INFINITY'` and `HISTFILESIZE='ANDBEYOND'`. Since they are non-numeric they save everything.

Why do negative values for history sizes clear the bash history?